# How to place a canvas over an image in android?

Tags: android, image, canvas, imageview, overlay

I would like to place a canvas over an imageview in android,how to overlay it directly.This is the current code & I want it overlapping it over an image

```
public class Tutorial2D extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new Panel(this));
}
```

}

How can I achieve this,any snippet will be greatly helpful.Thanks

Comment: Please Put xml code of ImageView and Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Place Image View and Canvas in a Relative Layout and make all layout params fill_parent.